# Max Admins In Developer Edition?

Tags: developer-edition

I just spun up a free developer org. I created accounts for two of my co-workers.  I can make one of them an Admin, but the other only has the option to be a 'Standard Salesforce User'.  Is that a restriction of the kind of org it is?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can only create as many admin accounts as you have full Salesforce licenses.

I believe you get two full licenses in the free dev edition (including the account created for yourself) but you can check in 'Company Information' tab in setup to see how many Salesforce licenses you have available.

Comment: Yes, free dev org is a maximum of 2 Salesforce licenses whichever profile and role combination is selected. 1 has to stay as a system admin to be able to run the org while the other can be used as an admin or any other profile depending on what you want to do with it. You can create users with other license types in a DE org, but the numbers are restricted to stop people trying to run a business off it.

Comment: Both this answer and @DaveHumm are right, although I would advise that if you *do* have a Production Salesforce organisation, you can go to `Setup > Deploy > Sandoxes` and you can create different types from there that give you much more relaxed restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

It all depends on the available licenses under Salesforce license type. **Salesforce** is a type of standard user license and . Here is the more information if it's not sufficient. You can find all these information under Company Information in your org setup.

As per documentation -

> **[Salesforce License Type](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=5)** - Designed for users who require full access
>   to standard CRM and Salesforce AppExchange apps. Users with this user
>   license are entitled to access any standard or custom app.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_available.htm&type=0